# Error: How to read empty cell in Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to read data from excel using POI. How can I check if that is an empty cell?

I don't know what is missing I think this should be working:

```
java.util.Iterator<Row> rows = worksheet.rowIterator();

HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
HSSFCell cellF1 = (HSSFCell) row.getCell(5);
if(cellF1.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
  String val = "";
}
```

I got error in if statement (null pointer), but only if I use this I can check that:

```
   while (rows.hasNext()) {
    HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
    java.util.Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
    while (cells.hasNext()) {
      HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
      if(cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
        String emptytype = "";
        System.out.println("empty");
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you are getting a null pointer, that would mean that cellF1 is undefined.
Are you sure the 6th cell is defined? Keep in mind that the cells are 0-based.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is normal behavior for the 1-argument version of `Row.getCell`. If you look at the API doc, it specifically states that `getCell` will return null if the cell is not defined. Many java functions exhibit this sort of behavior, so there is nothing wrong with coding to take this into account. So, one version of your code could be something like:

```
boolean hasDataFlag = true;    
HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);
hasDataFlag = (row != null);
HSSFCell cell = null;
if (hasDataFlag) cell = row.getCell(cellNumber);
hasDataFlag = (cell != null);
if (hasDataFlag) hasDataFlag = (cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
if (hasDataFlag) {
    // process the cell here
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the other version of `Row.getCell`, which takes a second argument that specifies the missing cell policy. This version would allow you to specify that `getCell` return a null cell for blank cells. So, here is some althernative code:

```
HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);
if (row != null) {
    HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cellNumber, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
    if (cell != null) {
        // process cell here
    }
}
```

Or, if you prefer, you could specify the policy as `Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK`. In that case, you would replace `if (cell != null)` with `if (cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)`.

Comment: if (hasDataFlag) cell = row.getCell(cellNumber);
hasDataFlag = (cell != null);
if (hasDataFlag) hasDataFlag = (cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
if (hasDataFlag) {


i don't get what its mean in logic but i just try and return no error thank u

Comment: You are welcome. Just to elaborate a little. The hasDataFlag is only set to true if the cell has data. So it is only true a) if the row is not null and b) if the cell is not null and c) if the cell type is not CELL_TYPE_BLANK. The reason I coded it that way is because it avoids a whole bunch of nested ifs. I could have coded it with nested ifs (as I did in the 2nd exaample), but I personally feel using the hasDataFlag results in cleaner code. But that is just my personal style; whatever is easier for you is fine.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the `CellIterator`, you'll only get the cells that have been defined at some point (no `null` cells, but you will get `blank` cells). If you want to get all cells, fetch them by index

By index, you'd do something like:

```
 Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
 for (int rowNumber = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); rowNumber <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNumber++) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);
    if (row == null) {
         // This row is completely empty
    } else {
         // The row has data
         for (int cellNumber = row.getFirstCellNum(); cellNumber <= row.getLastCellNum(); cellNumber++) {
             Cell cell = row.getCell(cellNumber);
             if (cell == null || cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                 // This cell is empty
             } else {
                 // This cell has data in it
             }
         }
    }
 }
```

Comment: this mean that u defined start row, end row, start cell, and end cell
thats cool. in my code just loop too cell and row that has data.
for me is still mystery how can the poi API differentiate the null and the empty cell  anyway thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(x, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
```

THis trick heped me a lot.
See if it's useful for you...

Answer (score 0):

```
int column, rownumber = 0; // just for showing the example code

Row row = sheet1.getRow(rownumber); // just for showing the example code

if (row!= null)
    mycell = row.getCell(0);
if (mycell != null && mycell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
    System.out.println(mycell.getStringCellValue());
}
else{
    System.out.println("whatever");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public String getCellData(String File_Name,int Sheet_Num, int Row_Num, int Col_Num) throws IOException{

```
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\"+File_Name+".xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileIn);
    XSSFSheet sheet=workbook.getSheetAt(Sheet_Num-1);
    XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(Row_Num-1);
    XSSFCell cell= row.getCell(Col_Num-1);
    String celldata;
    if(cell!=null){
    celldata= cell.getStringCellValue();
    }
    else 
        celldata ="";
    fileIn.close();
    return celldata;

    }
```