# Java import excel file(POI) into mysql about blank column

Tags: java, mysql, excel, nullpointerexception, apache-poi

I tried to import excel file into database(MySQL).

When Excel has empty column, Console window shows error message

...
Import rows 16
Import rows 17
Import rows 18
Import rows 19
Import rows 20
Import rows 21
Import rows 22
Import rows 23
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jdbcTest.main(jdbcTest.java:68)

How to fix this error?.  My source code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String url    =   "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dahan?characterEncoding=utf8";
    String user    =   "root";
    String password   =   "apmsetup";

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);  
        con.setAutoCommit(false);  
        PreparedStatement pstm1 = null ; 
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/hyunwoo/Downloads/Personal Contacts.xls");  
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );  
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);  
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0); 
        Row row;
        String del = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dahanMail`";
        /*String cre = "CREATE TABLE `dahanMail` (`Fullname`  varchar(50),`Firstname`  varchar(50),`Lastname`  varchar(50) ,`Nickname`  varchar(50),"
                + "`Company`  varchar(500),`Department`  varchar(500),`Position`  varchar(500),`Mail1`  varchar(50),"
                + "`Mail2`  varchar(50),`Number1`  varchar(50),`Number2`  varchar(50),`Number3`  varchar(50),"
                + "`PhoneNumber1`  varchar(50),`PhoneNumber2`  varchar(50),`Fax1`  varchar(50),`Fax2`  varchar(50),"
                + "`Address`  varchar(50),`Website`  varchar(50),`id`  int NOT NULL ,PRIMARY KEY (`id`))ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";*/
        pstm1 = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(del);
        pstm1.execute();
        del = "CREATE TABLE `dahanMail` (`Fullname`  varchar(50) ,`Firstname`  varchar(50),`Lastname`  varchar(50) ,"
                + "`id`  int NOT NULL ,PRIMARY KEY (`id`))ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";
        pstm1 = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(del);
        pstm1.execute();

        //String sql = "INSERT INTO dahanmail VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        String sql = "INSERT INTO dahanmail VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);


        for(int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
            row = sheet.getRow(i);

                   pstm.setString(1, row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
                   pstm.setString(2,row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
                   pstm.setString(3,row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
                /* pstm.setString(4,row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue());
                   pstm.setString(5,row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
                   pstm.setString(6,row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue());
                   pstm.setString(7,row.getCell(6).getStringCellValue());
                   pstm.setString(8,row.getCell(7).getStringCellValue());
                   pstm.setString(9,row.getCell(8).getStringCellValue());
                   pstm.setString(10,row.getCell(9).getStringCellValue());
                   pstm.setString(11,row.getCell(10).getStringCellValue());
                   pstm.setString(12,row.getCell(11).getStringCellValue());
                   pstm.setString(13,row.getCell(12).getStringCellValue());
                   pstm.setString(14,row.getCell(13).getStringCellValue());
                   pstm.setString(15,row.getCell(14).getStringCellValue());
                   pstm.setString(16,row.getCell(15).getStringCellValue());
                   pstm.setString(17,row.getCell(16).getStringCellValue());
                   pstm.setString(18,row.getCell(17).getStringCellValue());*/
                   pstm.setInt(4,(int)row.getCell(18).getNumericCellValue());
                   pstm.execute();
                   pstm.clearParameters();
                   System.out.println("Import rows "+i);
               // Do something useful with the cell's contents

        }
        con.commit();
        pstm.close();
        con.close();
        input.close();
        System.out.println("Success import excel to mysql table");
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what's mean full stack trace?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error How to read empty cell in excell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155428/error-how-to-read-empty-cell-in-excell)

Answer (score 0):

It is well-known (and documented in multiple other answers), that POI's get cell method will return null on empty cells.

Your code then calls getStringCellValue on the null, which causes the Exception.

Comment: thanks your comment, could you please show example source?